# EF + SQL Server: Code First or Database First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a system written in ASP.Net 2.0 Web Form. The framework that talks to MySQL Server is really cool. It reads all controls inside the server form tag or panel and does CRUD operations on the target table.

When I create the CRUD page, I just need to create the table in database user{id,name,password,createdate} and I just need to use id to be the exact column name in the table. The controls can be input/select/option/chekbox/textarea or even FCK Editor or CK Editor on the page. The framework loops through all the controls inside the Panel and save/edit/delete. If I want to add some new fields, email and mobile, I just need to add two controls on the page and add two more columns in the table. That's it. I don't have to change anything in page.aspx.cs file, Entity Layer, Business Layer or Data Access Layer. It is VERY easy to implement and maintain.

We want to upgrade the system to use ASP.Net 4 MVC3 with Entity Framework CT5. We will rebuild the whole system from the scratch. I was hoping some experts here could give me some pointers. I found the following two options to rebuild the system.

**1. Code First**
Our new system will do the exactly the same operations as the above framework. It will loop through all Request.Forms data and map them with its associate table in the database and save/update/delete all the data. To do this, view will post the form data, controller will accept the values with the Entity classes and save them to the database via EF. I still need to create ViewModel class to display data on View. If there is any change like adding email and mobile fields to user page, I still need to change three places view, entity(domain class) and ViewModel. I don't have to change anything in database as EF will automatically run ALTER TABLE to add two new fields. I still cannot figure out how to minimize the needs of both entity and viewmodel classes.

**2. Database First**
I really do not prefer this way but I will if this solution provides more flexible operations. I will create the columns in database, the system will dynamically create the ViewModel(I am still figuring out how to do that) reading all columns in the table, and display data on the page. When the view post data it needs to dynamically create the entity class and save the changes to the database.

EDIT:
Reasons of upgrading the current system.

- We want to use the power of new features in .Net 4, Linq, Entity Framework, unobtrusive javascript library, easifer to work with JSON data, Remote Validation(We can use RequireFieldValidator, RegExValidator in current system but they are limited, for eg: validation on input checkboxes and option), duck typing with var and interface.

Comment: It sounds like you don't even have an entity or business layer in your current system, just a data access layer (mysql framework). What are your reasons for the rewrite? Just to get rid of viewstate? Any other motivations?

Comment: It sounds like you don't need to rewrite the app. in the first place ...

Comment: It is not just to get rid of the ViewState. We usually do all the validation with RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator and some additional validation in page.aspx.cs file. We don't use Session or Viewstate much in current system either. I have added the reasons we want to upgrade the system. I am still thinking about the architecture before we start to make sure that the system is easy to maintain like the old system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our new system will do the exactly the same operations as the above
>   framework. It will loop through all Request.Forms data and map them
>   with its associate table in the database and save/update/delete all
>   the data. To do this, view will post the form data, controller will
>   accept the values with the Entity classes and save them to the
>   database via EF.

Someone please slap me if I'm missing something here, but these statements seem contradictory to me. If you want a system that will automatically parse the Request.Forms data and map them directly to a database table, then why would you need to use Entity Framework (or any other kind of middleware) at all? The point of EF, or any ORM, is to create a meaningful collection of conceptual data objects that represent your system's nouns. You then operate on those nouns, affecting their properties or accessing their behaviors, and let the ORM figure out how to map them to the tables + columns.

To answer your question, it sounds like you want the easiest solution, meaning the one where you have to write the least amount of code. If that is a correct assumption, then you might want to go with Database first. You can have EF generate your entity classes, but like you said, you will still have to either manually create viewmodel classes or come up with some kind of AOP (using T4 maybe) to generate these for you. But anytime you give a tool the power to generate something for you, you lose control over it.

I prefer code first / *conceptual* model first, but I also like to have complete control over everything in the application (aside from infrastructure concerns which can be delegated to tools and frameworks like AutoMapper, EF, T4MVC, etc). Yes, it is more work, because I have to create the entity classes, the viewmodel classes, and the views, (and controllers, and action filters, and html helpers, and rrrvrything else). If your domain is one where you can just map text boxes straight to database tables & columns, then maybe this would be overkill for you.

Comment: We have the clients who make changes all the time. Yes, I prefer to write code less and less dependency on Data Access Layer. Adding a new field shouldn't need to change in page.aspx.cs file, business logic or data access layer unless we need validation for that. I like the way code-first works. If I use code-first, there should be a way where I need to change in .cshtml file and domain. That's it. I still need to figure out how to avoid changing Command class and ViewModel in this case.